how to restart debugging in my main page when i have accidentaly of that and i'm unable to debug the code in my project
once i created a application using .net core and make some changes in there and than make it run but accidentally i trigger something on because of that when i mark to debug the code mark will be enabled until i haven't run that application but when i run that it shows as warning .And this issue i have faced in the Dot Net core .
I tried to find that point from where i can debug but didn't got anything . expecting the result to debug work fine and it's step to make it solve

What warning are you seeing? What version of Visual Studio are you using? We're going to need some more details. It's not exactly clear what's happening either.
